# distribution in Python 3

Tags: python, upload, installation, distribution, pypi

how to create distribution in Python 3 and how to install and upload it ?
i have made two folders nester and i made a list and a setup in it.

code of the list

```
movies = [
    "The Holy Grail", 1975, "Terry Jones & Terry Gilliam", 91,
    ["Graham Chapman",
        ["Michael Palin", "John Cleese", "Terry Gilliam", "Eric Idle", "Terry Jones"]
    ]
]
"""Hi!This is a file nester.py.this is my first comment """
def print_lol(the_list):
    """It is a function. we use it to not repeat the codes several times"""
    for each_item in the_list:
        if isinstance(each_item, list):
            print_lol(each_item)
        else :
            print(each_item)
    print_lol(movies)
```

code for setup

```
from distutils.core import setup
setup(
    name = 'nester',
    version = '1.0.0',
    py_modules = ['nester'],
    author = 'hfpython',
    author_email = 'hfpython@headfirstlabs.com',
    url = 'http://www.headfirstlabs.com',
    description = 'A simple printer of nested lists',
)
```

Comment: you may have pasted your code wrong as in its current form it isnt even valid python.

Answer (score 1):

> how to create distribution in Python 3 and how to install and upload it ?

Have a look at the tutorial "Packaging Python Projects" in *PyPA*'s Python Packaging User Guide:

- [Generating distribution archives](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/#generating-distribution-archives)
- [Uploading the distribution archives](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/#uploading-the-distribution-archives)

In short:

- Use `python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel` to create the distributions of your project.
- Use `python3 -m twine upload` to publish these distribtions to a Python project index, such as [PyPI](https://pypi.org/).

Comment: @robsiemb Agreed, but one has to consider the question. In this particular case I'd rather have this poorly researched question deleted.